# How to bring MessageBox to foreground in XML

Tags: installshield

The following is the InstallShield-2010 XML script with which the message will be displayed in the background. I want it to display in the foreground.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<SetupLanncher.Settings>
    <LauncherExtension>WarningMsgOp.dll</LauncherExtension> 
    <Setup>
        <Program>NDP40-KB982638-x86.exe</Program> 
        <Parameters>/q /norestart</Parameters> 
    </Setup>
    <PostWarningMessage>If you choose to reboot, you must log-in under the same user name. </PostWarningMessage> 
</SetupLanncher.Settings>
```

Here the message "If you choose to reboot....." will be displayed behind the installer window. I want it in foreground.

Comment: Sorry what tools are you using?

Comment: We are using Install shield 2010. Using the pre-requisites editor we trigger this.

Comment: Using C#, an exe is created and this xml is passed as a command line argument to that exe.